# UIImageView is not auto height in StackView with TableViewCell

Tags: swift, uitableview, uicollectionview, ios-autolayout, uistackview

[image]
This is the view hierarchy

I want the PhotoImgView auto height depends on the Image size

The image is download from server

I use KingFisher to download the image

when download finished, I set PhotoImgView's height constraint, and do layoutIfNeeded() in the cell class

but it's not update UI immediately

when I scroll to another cell, and let the cell invisible, and then scroll back, the cell would be right

How can I do this?

Same issue with the collectionView, I set collectionview's height constraint after collectionview.reloaData and get collectionview.contentSize.height

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Replace your current `layoutIfNeeded()` with this:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.layoutIfNeeded()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to call `setNeedsLayout()` before `layoutIfNeeded()`.

To get right result for collection view height you can try:

```
collectionView.reloadData()
collectionView.setNeedsLayout()
collectionView.layoutIfNeeded()
collectionView.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()
```